# Laravel Routing and Controller for Search

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building my first basic laravel web app, after following a few tutorials this is the first one I'm tinkering with on my own. I'm running into to some trouble with routing to a controller and then getting the correct url.

Ideally at this point I should only have two routes `/` and `/{user}`. On the homepage you can search via a form for the user and the form should take you to `/{user}`.

Routes (I have three cause I'm still trying to get this to work, and I think I need a POST):

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/{user}', 'HomeController@student');
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@studentLookUp');
```

Home Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('helpdesk');
}

public function student($user) {
    return View::make('selfservice')
        ->with('user', $user);
}

public function studentLookUp() {
    $user = Input::get('ID');

    return View::make('selfservice')
        ->with('user', $user);
}
```

Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left', 'role'=>'search'), array('action' => 'HomeController@student')) }}

  <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::text('ID', '', array('placeholder'=>'ID', 'class'=>'form-control') ); }}
  </div>

  {{ Form::button('Search', array('class'=>'btn btn-default')) }}  

{{ Form::close() }}
```

At this point I can search from the homepage ('/') and it will take me back to the homepage but with the searched for user which is how I want it to work except it doesn't have the right url of `homepage.com/username`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You mean `Route::get('/{user}', 'HomeController@student');` doesn't work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First register a route to listen your search request:

**1. Search Route:**
Register search route.

```
//route search 
Route::get('/search',['uses' => 'SearchController@getSearch','as' => 'search']);
```

**2. Search View:-**
Now create a search form in a view:-

```
<form  action="/search" method="get">
<input type="text"  name="q" placeholder="Search.."/>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**3. SearchController :**

Now create SearchController to handle your searching logic.
SearchController :

```
    <?php

    class SearchController extends \BaseController {


        public function getSearch()
        {
            //get keywords input for search
            $keyword=  Input::get('q');

            //search that student in Database
             $students= Student::find($keyword);

            //return display search result to user by using a view
            return View::make('selfservice')->with('student', $students);
        }

    }
```

Now you have to create one view **selfservice** to display your search result.

**4. Selfservice View:**

```
@foreach ($students as $key=> $student)
<div>
<a href="{{ URL::route('student.show', ['id' => $student->id]) }}">{{$student->name}}</a>
</div>              
@endforeach
```

Here for each student result, one link will be created. That link will be link:-

```
website.domain/{student}
```

**5. Update Routes for Student**

```
Route::get('/{student}',['uses' => 'HomeController@student','as' => 'student.show']);
```

---

**UPDATE** updated the answer to get student page directly

---

To redirect from search to `website.domain\{user}` follow these steps:-

**1. Modify SearchController**

```
<?php

class SearchController extends \BaseController {


    public function getSearch()
    {
        //get keywords input for search
        $keyword=  Input::get('q');

        //search that student in Database
         $student= Student::find($keyword);

        //redirect directly to student.show route with student detail
        return Redirect::route('student.show', array('student' => $student));
    }

}
```

**2.** Now add  a function for Route `student.show` in HomeController
`Route::get('/{student}',['uses' => 'HomeController@student','as' => 'student.show']);`

**In HomeController**

```
public function student($student)
{
    //here display student detail
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely helpful. At this point I can search for a user and they will show up, but the url is `homepage.com/search`. Any way to redirect to `homepage.com/username` after getting the query from the getSearch controller?

Comment: when search result be displayed,that time URL will be `website.domain/search?q=keyword` But in this search_result_view you will display all users and the URL of those users will be `website.domain/{user}`

Comment: first understand the flow `Homepage=>search=>search_result=>user_page`. There will be one intermediate view **search_result** between search and user view.After clicking on link available in sear_result view,page will be redirected to `website.domain/{user}`

Comment: That's what I thought. Anyway to be automatically routed without having to click the link on the search results page?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. That did it and I learned a few new tricks in Laravel I didn't know about!