# Laravel 5 Custom Route From Search Controller

Tags: php, laravel, custom-routes

I am very new to Laravel and did watch the free videos on Laracast to try and get as far as I could. I have a simple search input that takes in a zip code(ex:92804). It searches the database and finds the zip code, looks for a "provider" in the row and then returns a view depending on the provider that it finds(There are 4 providers at this moment). Ex: 92804->anaheim->ca->provider1 so it would return provider1's view with the data needed(city and state). I have gotten it to work up to this point, but when the view returns it has the url of

```
www.domain.com/search?q=92804.
```

How can I make a route or routes so it shows.

```
www.domain.com/{city}-{state}-{provider1}
```

Those would be variables so in the example it would be

```
www.domain.com/anaheim-ca-provider1
```

I did search on here and found this:(but I believe it's for an older version of Laravel) [Laravel Routing and Controller for Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641911/laravel-routing-and-controller-for-search)

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('search',['uses' => 'SearchController@getSearch','as' => 'search']);
Route::get('/{city}-{state}-{zipcode}',['uses' => 'PagesController@provider1','as' => 'search.provider1']);
Route::get('/{city}-{state}-{zipcode}',['uses' => 'PagesController@provider2','as' => 'search.provider2']);
Route::get('/{city}-{state}-{zipcode}',['uses' => 'PagesController@provider3','as' => 'search.provider3']);
Route::get('/{city}-{state}-{zipcode}',['uses' => 'PagesController@provider4','as' => 'search.provider4'])
```

;

My form in the welcome view:

```
<form  action="search" method="get">
    <input type="text"  name="q" placeholder="Search.."/>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

PagesController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
    {

        return view('welcome');

    }
public function provider1()
        {

            return view('providers/provider1/provider1Search');

        }
public function provider2()
            {

                return view('providers/provider2/provider2Search');

            }
public function provider3()
            {

                return view('providers/provider3/provider4Search');

            }
public function provider4()
            {

                return view('providers/provider4/provider4Search');

            }

}
```

SearchController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
     public function getSearch(Request $request) 
        {
            $keyword =  $request->input('q');

            $data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM `TABLE 13` WHERE `Zip Code` = '$keyword'");

        $city = strtolower($data[0]->City);
        $state = strtolower($data[0]->State);
        $provider = strtolower($data[0]->{'Provider Name'});
        $zipcode = $data[0]->{'Zip Code'};

            if ($data[0]->{'Provider Name'})
                {
                    switch ($data[0]->{'Provider Name'})
                        {
                            case "provider1":
                                return redirect()->route('search.provider1',[$city,$state,$zipcode])->with('data',$data);
                                break;
                            case "provider2":
                                return return redirect()->route('search.provider2',[$city,$state,$zipcode])->with('data',$data);
                                break;
                            case "provider3":
                                return return redirect()->route('search.provider3',[$city,$state,$zipcode])->with('data',$data);
                                break;
                            case "provider4":
                                return return redirect()->route('search.provider4',[$city,$state,$zipcode])->with('data',$data);
                                break;
                        }
                }   
        }
}
```

My Views:

1. provider1Search
2. provider2Search
3. provider3Search
4. provider4Search
5. welcome

In the views for the providerSearch I call the city,state,provider like this:

```
{{$data[0]->City}},{{$data[0]->State}},{{$data[0]->{'Provider Name'}}
```

Those are the variables I would like to use in the custom route

Example:

1. zip code = 85257 = www.domain.com/scottsdale-az-provider1
2. zip code = 92804 = www.domain.com/anaheim-ca-provider2
3. zip code = 60605 = www.domain.com/chicago-il-provider3
4. zip code = 01527 = www.domain.com/millbury-ma-provider4

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but can't you just make the search post request to `q=xxxxx`, and the let the controller return a `redirect()->route()` after fetching the data?

Comment: Thanks Joel. I was confused about what a 'redirect()->route()' was but I read a little  and was able to get the url structure I wanted but now the view gives me an error saying "undefined variables". How can I redirect back to the route and still use the variables for city and state in the view?

Comment: Assuming you have the variables for city, state and provider, and your route has been correctly setup, you should be able to supply them in the route call like e.g. `route('my-route-name', [$city, $state, $provider])`.

Comment: Thank your for your help. The route does work now with the format you said before. So the url does change and use those variables. But if I call {{$city}} in the HTML of the view that is returned. It says undefined. So now the URL is correct but I can not use the variable in the view(html) now.

Comment: Did you supply the variable to the view from your controller method?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. Do I need to add the variable to each provider method in the PagesController? I updated my code to show what I am now working with. Thanks again for the help and time.

Comment: Yes, afraid so. Please see this link for information on passing variables: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Thank you Joel for your help. I will have to do it that way. Is there a way to mark your comment as correct ? I would like to give you credit for your time and help.

Comment: Afraid not, but that's fine. I'm happy to help. :)